# Collision detection between sprite and drawDot? (javascript)

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I have this sprite (image of a square)

```
this.player = new cc.Sprite();
this.player.initWithFile(res.player_png, cc.rect(0,0,50,50));
this.player.setAnchorPoint(cc.p(0.5, 0.5));
this.player.setPosition(cc.p(this.size.width/2, this.size.height/2));
this.addChild(this.player, 0);
```

And i have this dot

```
this.dot = new cc.DrawNode.create();
this.dot.drawDot(cc.p(
    this.size.width/2, 
    this.size.height/2), 
    100, 
    cc.color(12, 156, 194, 100));

this.addChild(this.circle, 0);
```

How do i check if they collide? i know how to do it if the both where sprites but not if one is drawn by DrawNode.

Answer (score 1):

When dot is drawn in DrawNode - it's just drawn on a canvas, you can't access it's geometry separately afterwards. What you can do, is store the geometry in a separate array:

```
var dotGeometry = [];

this.dot = new cc.DrawNode.create();
this.dot.drawDot(cc.p(
this.size.width/2, 
this.size.height/2), 
100, 
cc.color(12, 156, 194, 100));

dotGeometry.push( cc.rect(this.size.width/2-50, this.size.height/2-50, 100, 100) );
```

(I used cc.rect for rectangular intersection, you can change the shape to make it more accurate)
Then you can just use cc.rectIntersectsRect as always (cc.rect is just a geometry presentation (4 values) so it won't affect performance/waste much of memory)